# Possible over-current issue in Arduino transistor circuit?

Tags: arduino, transistors

I have made the circuit illustrated below.  It uses a Sparkfun ProMicro to turn a pump on and off based on the signal from an Adafruit light sensor. I am using a signal from the ProMicro to the 2n2222 to switch 5v to the pump.  I have used this circuit in the past on other pumps with no problems.  I think this pump might draw too much current (about 550 mA at 5v) as the 2n2222 is getting very hot.  Circuit will run for a little while, then stop.  Will run again after it cools down.

Can I swap the 2n2222 for a higher current transistor like the ztx1053?  Do I need to upgrade the 1N4001 too?  Or am I on the wrong track, maybe there is another problem?

[image: circuit diagram]

Answer (score 3):

You would be better off using a logic-level MOSFET for the transistor. Even a small SOT-23 part such as the [AO3400A](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3400A.pdf) can switch several amperes. The 1N400x diode is fine.

The LM7805 will also get quite hot, and needs a heatsink. A good switching 5V supply would be better- run cooler and waste less energy.